# Linear positioning in Framelayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout, android-viewgroup

Using FrameLayout, how can I position child elements vertically to begin with? I am choosing Framelayout because, eventually, I want to move one child over another, but am unable to position them linearly to begin with.

**Begin**

[image]

**End**

[image]

Comment: Consider revising your question!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the top view you can set the layout_marginTop of the bottom view to be equal to that value.

Otherwise you could switch to a RelativeLayout and use layout_below to position the bottom view relative to the top view.

Answer (score 0):

`Using FrameLayout, how can I position child elements vertically to begin with?`

by vertically i am assuming   `| child 1 | child 2 |` . For this you can use a linear layout with `android:orientation="vertical"`. Enclose the two child layouts within this layout and use `android:layout_weight` in the child and `android:weightsum` in the enclosing layout.

if you want to keep that horizontal set orientation to horizontal.